# Electron app createWriteStream throwing ENOENT error

Tags: node.js, electron, fs, enoent

I'm trying to download files to the filesystem in an electron app. My code, in the main thread, looks like this:

```
const dir = `${__dirname}/media`;
if (!fs.existsSync(dir)){
    fs.mkdirSync(dir);
}

const file = fs.createWriteStream(`${dir}/${name}`);
file.on("open", function() {
    const request = http.get(url, function(response) {
        response.pipe(file);

        response.on('end', function() {
            file.close();
            ...
        });
    });

    request.on('error', function(err) {
        ...
    });
});
```

This works when running in development using `electron .` But after I build it with `electron-builder`, I get the error in an alert:

> Uncaught Exception:
>   Error: ENOENT, media/uploads_2016_02_BASF_Holistic_Program.jpg not found in /Users/nicholasstephan/Desktop/XXXXXXX/dist/Mac/XXXXXX.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar
>       at notFoundError (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:109:19)
>       at Object.module.(anonymous function) [as open] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:209:16)
>       at WriteStream.open (fs.js:1890:6)
>       at new WriteStream (fs.js:1876:10)
>       at Object.fs.createWriteStream (fs.js:1831:10)
>       at next (/Users/nicholasstephan/Desktop/XXXXXXXX/dist/Mac/XXXXXXXX.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/media.js:19:18)
>       at /Users/nicholasstephan/Desktop/XXXXXXXX/dist/Mac/XXXXXXXX.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/media.js:52:4
>   ...

where the `media.js`, ln 19, being referred to is the `const file = fs.createWriteStream(`${dir}/${name}`);` line in the code.

I've tried the solutions offered in about a dozen other similar stackoverflow answers, but none have fixed the problem.

What's going on here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built Electron app uses the [Asar](https://github.com/electron/asar) format. Asar is an archive format (it's really just one big file) though in Electron you are able to read from it as if it were a standard directory.

I presume (though I have not seen it explicitly documented) that it is not possible to write to an Asar with the `fs` functions. In any case there are almost certainly more appropriate locations to write data.

Try writing to a different path. Electron provides a number of useful paths using [`app.getPath(name)`](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/app/#appgetpathname) so you could for example write to the `userData` directory which holds configuration files for your app.