# How to change the path in electron so it saves files to different directory not packed in app.asar file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am building an electron app which will save files after building the app, and when I let **asar=true** in package.json file, it gives me errors Enont and does not save anything but when I make it **asar=false** it worked and save files. I want to let it **asar=true** and change the directory to which files are supposed to be saved ..
here is my index.js file

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

btnCreate = document.getElementById('btnCreate')
btnRead = document.getElementById('btnRead')
btnDelete = document.getElementById('btnDelete')
fileName = document.getElementById('fileName')
fileContents = document.getElementById('fileContents')

let pathName = path.join(__dirname, 'Files')


btnCreate.addEventListener('click', function(){

    let file     = path.join(pathName, fileName.value)
    let contents = fileContents.value
    fs.writeFile(file, contents, function(err){
        if(err){
            return console.log(err)
        }
        console.log("The File Was Created")

    })

})
```

I found this answer :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42508682/9008535

but I am very new to Electron and I do not know how to make it ?

Comment: are you running the above code in render process or main process?

Comment: I am running this in main

Comment: try this `let homePath = app.getPath("home")` , btw index.js is the file imported in index.html. so this is run in renderer. main.js is main process. import app `const app = require('electron').remote.app` in renderer

Comment: thanks @namila007 ..  it worked now .. but I want it to save to the main folder of the project , how I can write the path to make it save to the main folder ?

Comment: I will add a complete answer :)

Comment: any updates @sami ?

Comment: thanks your answer helped me a lot

Comment: no problems , :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the installation path you can use `app.getAppPath()` in your main.js . But in the production this will return your `asar` path

> `app.getAppPath()` Returns String - The current application directory.

In your `main.js` you can use following code to write in to your installation folder;

```
const myInstalledDir = path.join(app.getAppPath(),"..",".."); // root installation path
const fs = require("fs")
const path = require("path")
//write something to root installation folder
fs.writeFileSync(path.join(myInstalledDir,"myfile.txt"),"sdfsdf")
//reading
console.log(fs.readFileSync(path.join(myInstalledDir,"myfile.txt")))
```